# Sylius Inventory Bundle: Unrecognized option "unit" under "sylius_inventory.classes"

Tags: symfony, sylius

I'm trying to install **Sylius Inventory Bundle** but while updating schema, I get this error:   **[Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Exception\InvalidConfigurationException]
  Unrecognized option "unit" under "sylius_inventory.classes"**

I am following [the documentation](http://sylius.readthedocs.org/en/latest/bundles/SyliusInventoryBundle/installation.html#container-configuration)

InventoryUnit entity:

```
<?php

// src/App/AppBundle/Entity/InventoryUnit.php
namespace App\AppBundle\Entity;

use Sylius\Bundle\InventoryBundle\Entity\InventoryUnit as BaseInventoryUnit;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="app_inventory_unit")
 */
class InventoryUnit extends BaseInventoryUnit
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;
}
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configuration should be:

```
sylius_inventory:
    driver: doctrine/orm
    backorders: true
    classes:
        inventory_unit:
            model: App\AppBundle\Entity\InventoryUnit
        stockable:
            model: App\AppBundle\Entity\Book
```

[Documentation](http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/bundles/SyliusInventoryBundle/installation.html#container-configuration) needs an [update](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius-Docs/pull/311).

Comment: After correct that config error, I get this:
Fatal error: Class 'Sylius\Bundle\InventoryBundle\Entity\InventoryUnit' not found in ...\App\AppBundle\Entity\InventoryUnit.php on line 19

Comment: Can you gist `App\AppBundle\Entity\InventoryUnit.php` please?

Comment: It's `Sylius\Component\Core\Model\InventoryUnit`, see https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/blob/master/src/Sylius/Component/Core/Model/InventoryUnit.php